# Why example code with two variable names in for..of loop does not work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

Why example code with two variable names in for..of loop does not work? Is it so because ECMAScript 6 is still in beta mode?

Here is the code:

```
let arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    for (let [index,element] of arr.entries()) {
        console.log(index + '. ' + element);
    }
```

The error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ('[', of course)
```

My browser: Google Chrome 39.0.2171.65 (64-bit)

Comment: I don't think Chrome supports Harmony.

Comment: That's ES6 syntax and it won't work in Chrome.

Comment: Does Chrome really say *of course*? Wow.

Comment: @Scimonster, what was confusing is that for..of works on my version of Google Chrome and it is part of Harmony. Just these brackets apparently are not supported yet.

Bergi, no, it doesn't. It is my comment, but I think it is pretty obvious. I am sorry if it is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if you are trying it in an environment that supports ES6 syntax!  Chrome, as of today, does not.

Checkout [LearnHarmony.org](http://learnharmony.org/).  You can enter this code into the REPL loop and see that it works there.  If you'd like to use this syntax today in your project, you need to transpile.  Look at [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) or [6to5](https://github.com/6to5/6to5) for doing something like that..